# Is Rails controller documentation a best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation

Reek gem identifies a smell in my code such that it lacks documentation in classes. But I was wondering if that should be applied to controllers as well.

In a good codebase, a controller would be very thin, just dealing with the requests and delegating all the logic to models/services/helpers. Hence not much to document to begin with. Not being an API and especially not an open one, I don't see a good reason to add documentation to it.

Would like to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: I usually at least annote the URI/method for each action. Doing a top level class description seems superflous as its usually pretty obvious what a controller does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no need for documentation in controllers. But if you want reek to not identify this smell then you can add a one-liner explanation of the controller or add

```
#:nodoc: all
```

at the top in your controllers (this is what I do). This is suggested by [rubycop](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/Documentation) gem

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware that I can disable that, just wondering if I should. Is there any particular reason you personally don't think there is a need for it?

Comment: As max commented, it's usually pretty obvious what controller does. If your controller is doing other than obvious things then top level documentation is good. It's good to write a description of custom actions in the controllers.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. Nice, thanks